# Cocoa: AVAudioRecorder Fails to Record

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudiorecorder

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
err = nil;
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}

NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:40000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];

// Create a new dated file
NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
NSString *caldate = [now description];
NSString *recorderFilePath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.caf", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER, caldate] retain];

NSLog(recorderFilePath);
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];
err = nil;
recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
if(!recorder){
    NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                               message: [err localizedDescription]
                              delegate: nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    return;
}

//prepare to record
[recorder setDelegate:self];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;
if (! audioHWAvailable) {
    UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                               message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                              delegate: nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [cantRecordAlert show];
    [cantRecordAlert release]; 
    return;
}
// [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector( updateTimerDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
// [recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)10 ]; 
// [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector( updateTimerDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You never call:

```
[recorder record];
```

... so the recorder never starts recording.

This is the kind of mistake I never, ever make. At least, it's the kind of mistake I will never admit to making. ;-)

Comment: thank you, but iam using record for duration method know why its not working

Comment: sorry i commented that one right, i tried that also iam not getting

Comment: how i can save an audio file to mp3 or is their any api to convert from caf to mp3 audio file format.